# How do you abbreviate "Government"?

Tags: formality, abbreviations, contractions, writing-style

As far as I can tell there are *eight* ways to abbreviate or write the contracted form "government".

1. gov or Gov
2. gov. or Gov.
3. gov't or Gov't
4. govt. or Govt. (with the full stop/period)

Are any of these forms considered incorrect?

In formal writing I know it is never advisable to write contractions but I imagine there must be exceptions to the rule, consequently which is the preferred version? Is there a rule which explains *how* polysyllabic words ought to be contracted?

---

**Edit** April 5th 2014
I did a little research on Google [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Govt,govt,Gov,gov&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4;,Govt;,c0;,s0;;Govt;,c0;;govt;,c0;;GOVT;,c0;.t4;,govt;,c0;,s0;;Govt;,c0;;govt;,c0;;GOVT;,c0;.t4;,Gov;,c0;,s0;;gov;,c0;;Gov;,c0;;GOV;,c0;.t4;,gov;,c0;,s0;;gov;,c0;;Gov;,c0;;GOV;,c0), comparing Govt/govt with Gov/gov (Google Ngram appears to be unreliable with apostrophes and the period/full stop) and came up with these two.

[image]
[image]

Comment: All. Depends on exact implication desired, context, domain, even geography. http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviations/GO/30 http://www.abbreviations.com/GOV  http://www.allacronyms.com/GOVT/Government/106826

Comment: @Kris When you say "all" do you mean they are all acceptable forms of abbreviating government? Then, how do I know when to use which? I think ".gov" is preferable for domains, but I'm muddled about the rest.

Comment: Yes, they are all acceptable forms of abbreviating government -- it depends. *gov* is used as TLD and sometimes in media headlines (Gov Relaxes Rules), *govt.* and *gov't.* are the more common abbreviations in general English usage. The period (full stop) is always there. Capitalization depends on context. This may help: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gov%2Cgovt%2CGov%2C+Govt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Couldn't you write this as an answer?

Comment: I would not use a period and an apostrophe together. One or the other.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I wonder what a period has got to do with the presence or otherwise of an apostrophe. Are they such bitter rivals? :)

Comment: @Kris  I have seen "Gov't" and "gov't" without the period, if it's true that the period is always there that means there are possibly  *ten* different abbreviations!

Comment: As far as the TLD *.gov* (read: 'dot gov') is considered, it's more of a special purpose code than a general abbreviation, so it doesn't count. The only abbreviation is *govt* with or without an apostrophe, with or without a period, depending on context, etc. (Not to forget the exception already mentioned, that some media may fancy using 'gov', esp., in headlines.)

Comment: @Why don't you write your comments into an answer? I'd upvote it.

Comment: You may find this nGram clearer. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=govt%2Cgovt+.%2CGovt%2CGovt+.%2Cgov%2Cgov+.%2CGov%2CGov+.&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all of the reference books I consulted note that *gov* (or *gov.*) can be an abbreviation either for *government* or for *governor*. In the United States at least, that dual meaning can lead to problems of ambiguity: many U.S. readers are likely to interpret the *Gov* in a headline such as "Gov Relaxes Rules" as being short for *Governor* [of the state where the newspaper is published]. For that reason, in the United States, including the final *t* is a sensible practice.

None of the various sources I consulted recommend the abbreviation *gov't*; instead, they divide their preference between *govt.* (with a period) and *govt* (without one).

Proponents of *govt.* (with a period) include *The Random House College Dictionary* (1984), which actually prefers *Govt.* but includes *govt.* as an alternative; the Facts on File *Concise Dictionary of Acronyms and Initialisms* (1988); *Encarta World English Dictionary* (1999), *Webster's II New College Dictionary* (1999), *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, Fourth Edition (2000), and *The New Oxford American Dictionary* (2001).

Proponents of *govt* (without a period) include *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary, Eleventh Edition* (2003) and *The Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, Tenth Edition  (2002).

The modern legitimacy of both *govt.* and *govt* is well established by these sources. Nevertheless, my favorite bit of style advice on the subject is this from *The Associated Press Stylebook and Libel Manual* (1994):

> **government** Always lowercase, never abbreviate: *the federal government*, *the state government*, *the U.S. government*.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Mari-Lou A; I deleted the now-obsolete final paragraph of my answer. Just to reiterate a point I touched on early in my answer, in U.S. results (at least) any comparison of _gov_ vs. _govt_ as an abbreviation for _government_ is likely to be skewed in search engine results by the fact that, wheres _govt_ is short only for _government_, _gov_ may be short for _government_ or _governor_.

Comment: Sadly, I realized that but I don't know how to exclude *governor* from the results. I suppose there isn't a way.

Answer (score 1):

2019 corpus update (case-insensitive; see also the [case-sensitive version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjEoH.png)):

[image: ngrams for gov vs govt vs gov't, case-insensitive, 1970-2019]

In 2010, for the first time in 90 years, `gov` beat `govt`. It has maintained this edge ever since, though it's not growing and I wonder how much of that is from domain names (as noted in [TrevorD's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121662/112762)).

We can try to control for .gov (and .gov.uk, etc.) by looking only at the capitalized form, Gov vs Govt vs Gov't, in which we see Govt still has a bit of a lead, reinforcing [Sven Yargs's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121745/112762)'s preference for `govt`:

[image: ngarms for Gov vs Govt vs Gov't, unsmoothed, 2009-2019]

My advice: **don't abbreviate it unless you're pressed for space** (such as in a diagram, table, or tweet). When you abbreviate, use `govt`. Capitalize only at the beginning of a sentence or when using [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case).

Regarding that trailing period: I personally like omitting it (since that creates no confusion), but Sven has some great references suggesting it's more a common style to include it.

Answer (score -1):

#### Domains

**.gov** is the domain for the US government.
**.gov.uk** is the domain for the UK government.

Commenting that something "is *preferable* for domains" seems inappropriate, because the domains have already been determined and it's merely a case of using what exists. Preference does not come into it.

#### Capitalisation

My choice of whether to capitalise the initial letter of the *abbreviation* would exactly follow whether I would capitalise the initial letter of the *full word* in the respective context.

A domain name extension would, of course, *never* be capitalised.

[The comments below apply equally to capitalised and non-capitalised versions of the respective abbreviations.]

#### Period

I have always understood that conventional practice on whether to include a period at the end of an abbreviation is to *include* one if the *last letter of the full word* is *not* present in the abbreviation, and *not* to include one if it *is* present.

Hence I would omit it from ***Gov't*** and ***Govt***,
but include a period in ***Gov.***.

#### Apostrophe

I doubt that there is any standard on whether to include an apostrophe in the abbreviation ***Gov't***, nor any consistency within any particular government, let alone within governments from different English-speaking countries.

My personal preference is normally to include one.

#### *t* or no *t*

Although I don't have anything off-hand to back this up, I would suggest that inclusion of the ***t*** is possibly more common (in the UK), and that the abbreviation ***gov.*** without the ***t*** has become more prevalent from its usage as domain name extensions.

Comment: So, you would never capitalize the abbreviation in the middle of a sentence because government is not a proper noun. Correct?

Comment: Probably not, unless it were being used as part of a formal name or naming a specific government, e.g. *the British Government*.  I'm not always consistent, but I tend to prefer to avoid over-capitalisation. And then I would probably spell out the whole word, rather than abbreviate it (except in, say, an informal e-mail).

Comment: I believe the rule for periods is different in the US and UK. In AmE we usually use a period even with the final letter. So we write Mr. and dr. rather than Mr and dr, for example. Also, here Gov. is used more for Governor than government.

Answer (score -1):

I think Govt. is more appropriate. There is a scale to denote the justice or balance or end.